# Excel MAX IF Function To Ingore N/A Error And Zero Date (1/0/00)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data. I need to get the most recent date. However, I'm unable to exclude both the Error and 1/0/00 at the same time.

I have tried using `=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(B16:E16)),B16:E16))` but that returns 1/0/00 as the MAX.

Also, I have tried `=MAX(IF(B15:E15>1/0/0,B15:E15))` to get rid of the zero but that doesn't quite work either. Also, when I combine the two, it really doesn't work.

In the example below, the output for row 2 under "Date-Max" would be 7/28/16.

```
Date1   Date2   Date3   Date4   Date-Max
7/26/16 #N/A    #N/A    1/0/00  Output
7/20/16 7/28/16 1/0/00  1/0/00  Output
7/25/16 #N/A    #N/A    1/0/00  Output
7/25/16 #N/A    #N/A    1/0/00  Output
7/20/16 #N/A    #N/A    1/0/00  Output
7/25/16 7/29/16 #N/A    1/0/00  Output
7/17/16 #N/A    8/1/16  1/0/00  Output
```

Need the max output for each row.

Comment: Your formulas work correctly only as array formulas, instead of Enter press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER once you've typed them.

Comment: There’s an old saying: “Crawl before you walk; walk before you run.”  Your formulas don’t work even if every cell in the range contains a valid date in the 21st century.  If you had tested that, you might have gotten a clue that you were barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: P.S. Your question is confusing.  You have dates in (what appear to be) the first four columns, and yet you talk about columns `B:E`.  And you give formulas referencing rows 15 and 16, and then state the desired result for row 2 (which is actually row 3, assuming that the headers are in row 1).  … … … … … … … … … …  Thank you for posting your data as text rather than an image, but part of the point of doing that is to allow people to copy your data and paste into their spreadsheets and experiment with it.  Your inconsistent presentation makes that difficult.

Comment: Hey G-Man, sorry about that. I was copying and pasting from the values I was working with and didn't catch that. Next time, I'll just get the whole sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider data in **A1** through **A10**, use this *array formula*:

```
=MAX(IF(NOT(ISNA(A1:A10)),A1:A10,0))
```

[image]

It is not necessary to test for zero, since *MAX()* will pick any positive value over zero anyway.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.